# I'm getting the notificaiton to update to 14.04 but it says theres no new release. What gives!

Tags: do-release-upgrade, hardware-enablement-stack

When I first log in I see this http://screencloud.net/v/Feqm

```
:~$ ssh root@[Redacted]
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Wed Aug  6 11:32:38 EDT 2014

  System load:  0.37              Processes:           110
  Usage of /:   5.3% of 37.17GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 12%               IP address for eth0: [REDACTED]
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/



Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is going out of support
on 2014-08-07.  After this date security updates for critical parts (kernel
and graphics stack) of your system will no longer be available.

For more information, please see:
http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL

To upgrade to a supported (or longer supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade 

OR

* Install a newer HWE version by running:
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty linux-image-generic-lts-trusty

and reboot your system.
```

When I run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I end up getting this.

```
root@glass:~# sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
root@glass:~#
```

So far I've tried to replace the sources.list with a list from another server I'm running with another datacenter.  But I'm sure I'm just missing something simple / obvious.  The VPS provider I'm running this with is kind of new so they have a lot of growing pains that I have to live through so this may also be part of the issue.

Comment: There was a bit of a hold-up on releaseing the 12.04 ->14.04 upgrade, but it should be out soon, probably on a Thurs. or Fri.

Comment: Thats actually awesome to hear.  I would rather they take their time anyways I generally wont do a release upgrade for about 3 months into the release cycle anyways its just bad karma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` among other things. Here is the extensive guide I based my answer off of: [Guide](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2014/06/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-server-12-04-to-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts.html).